# Optimize search of duplicate n-uplets between two tables

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I want to calculate a duplicate n-uplets between two tables (without association).

Suppose that we have two tables :

### Table A : (firstname, lastname, email ...)

### N-uplets:

TOTO/ TOTO/ TOTO@test.com ...

TITI/ TITI/ TITI@test.com ...

### Table B : (firstname, lastname, email ...)

### N-uplets:

TOTI/ TOTI/ TOTO@test.com ...

TITI/ TITI/ TATI@test.com ...

My request should get TOTO and TITI from table A.

```
   $query = $this->createQueryBuilde('a');
   $query
       ->innerJoin(B::class, 'b',
                  'with',
                   "(a.lastName = b.lastName AND a.firstname = b.firstName) 
                    OR a.email = b.email"
        )
   ;
```

This request works, but I have 10k n-uplets in Table A and 40k in table B. The execution is slow :/

Any idea to optimize it ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You need some indexes. Since you have an `OR` condition I would create two indexes:

```
create index ix1 on tableb (lastname, firstname);

create index ix2 on tableb (email);
```

The `OR` condition requires two scans.

Comment: I tried this solution, it optimized a little :/  Thank's :)

Comment: If you really want an optimized query, you can post the execution plan and I can help you read it, and improve it.